# Wordpress / Woocommerce site performance fluctuations

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, woocommerce, newrelic

I've launched WooCommerce store about two weeks ago. Most of the time the site works fine but there are peaks when the site slows down drastically. The site is hosted on Kinsta (business 1 plan) so it shouldn't be about the slow host. I have enabled New Relic monitoring (free tier) and every single time the slow transactions are these two:

1. get_filesystem_method (related to WPML?)
2. MySQL query which is always like this: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM *some_table* (`wp_usermeta`, `wp_options` `wpc_icl_strings` etc. It varies)

These two transactions happen both separately and at the same time and they occur on all pages during the slowdown. This makes it very hard to find out the problem. I have cloned the site and tried disabling plugins but because I'm not able to reproduce the problem I can't get forward.

I also contacted WPML support but they haven't checked the [topic](https://wpml.org/forums/topic/slow-call-to-get_filesystem_method/) yet.

Here is some screenshots of the new relic data:

[Overview of the peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmYtJ.png)

[Slow query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0CyB.png)

[get_filesystem_method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4NHB.png)

Any ideas what it could be? How should I proceed debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Changing hosting provider magically fixed the problem.